# displaying only next instance of a class when clicking on another

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm displaying a div with text when I click on .read-more class. The problem I'm facing is that when I click .read-more all instances of .slide-box are being displayed instead of only the one just below the specific .read-more.

Here is my current code:

```
$( ".read-more" ).click(function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $('div.slide-box').css('position','static');
    $('.accordion .txt-box').css('border','none');
    $('.accordion .txt-box p').css('margin','0');
});
```

I tried using :

```
 $.next('div.slide-box').css('position','static');
```

without success..

How can I only target only the next instance of div with class .slide-box ?

here is the markup:

```
<div class="txt-box">
<h2>txt</h2>
<h3>txt</h3>                                        
<p>txt txt.....<span class="read-more"> -Read More</span></p>
<a class="opener" href="#">plus</a>
</div>
<div class="slide-box">
<p>Itxt txt.....<span class="read-less"> -Less</span></p>                                    
</div>
```

I'm hoping to be able to keep the markup as it is since it is a wp site..

Comment: Show the HTML structure of the buttons and DIVs please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference next of this. Try this:

```
$(this).next('div.slide-box').css('position','static');
```

Based on the provided markup you can try this code:

```
$(this).closest('.txt-box').next('div.slide-box').css('position','static');
```

Here it is assumed that you will have a div with class 'txt-box' and a div with class 'slide-box' next to it for each instance.

Comment: $(this).next('div.slide-box').css('position','static'); doesn't seem to target anything

Comment: You have to show the html. Here I am assuming your slide-box DIV is right next to each "read-more".

Answer (score 1):

JQuery's `.find()` may help. http://api.jquery.com/find/

Below will actually return the first element on the page instead of the 'next' as pointed out in comments.

> This returns an array of jquery elements: `$('div.slide-box')`
>
> So this should work `$('div.slide-box')[0]`.

Comment: This will always select the first instance if there were more DIVs. The opening poster wants to show NEXT div.

Comment: Yeah true Nawed. I've included the find method which I think will be helpful (find element within the current element) so I will make that the focus of the answer.

Comment: We're having problems because we can't see your markup. Post that and we will be able to work out the correct selector.